# How to center text in text widget in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, select, tk-toolkit

I have a text widget

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("cloth")
root.geometry("500x500")
l = Text(root, width=46, bg="White",relief = "solid", font="Arial 9",height=1,bd=1)
l.configure(state='normal')
l.configure(state='disabled')
l.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

I want to center text
but if I select then only the text is selected, no space is selected

Comment: You should use ```l.pack(expand=1)```

Comment: no i want center a text in text widget i dont know how replace question

Answer (score 0):

You need add `tag_configure("tag_name", justify='center')` and `tag_add("tag_name", "1.0", "end")`

#### Here is the example

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("cloth")
root.geometry("500x500")
l = Text(root, width=46, bg="White",relief = "solid", font="Arial 9",height=1,bd=1)
l.tag_configure("tag_name", justify='center')
l.insert("1.0", "How to center text in text widget in tkinter ?")
l.tag_add("tag_name", "1.0", "end")
l.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, no way to do it without adding spaces

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
T1 = tk.Text(root)
T1.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
T1.insert(1.0, " ")
T1.tag_add("center", "1.0", "end")
T1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this is not answer